# Variable number using easy pie chart library

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a very simple way to change the value on submit on a variable which dictates the percentage of the pie chart using easy pie library.

Here is the code it is very easy to use.

```
<span class="chart" data-percent="0">
<span class="percent"></span>
</span>
<input id="value1" type="text" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" />
<span class="btn js_update" onclick="output();">Update chart</span>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

The above starts the pie chart at 0% by setting the data-percent to 0

```
<script src="../dist/easypiechart.js"></script>
<script>
    function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var chart = window.chart = new EasyPieChart(document.querySelector('span'), {
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        delay: 3000,
        barColor: 'purple',
        trackColor: 'pink',
        scaleColor: false,
        lineWidth: 20,
        trackWidth: 20,
        lineCap: 'butt',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            this.el.children[0].innerHTML = Math.round(percent);
        }
    });




    document.querySelector('.js_update').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        chart.update(Math.floor(val2));
    });

});
</script>
```

the above builds the pie chart - however I need a simple input field and submit to change the value of the variable `val1` I tried to use a return value but will not allow for that, I tried using jquery to write the value out but still not sure but I am sure it is a simple thing?

Comment: Can you add the html code of the form, including the submit button?

Comment: Hey I have updated the example for you - I have been trying to fix it myself in the mean time - so the submit button outputs data for me but I am wanting to get it into that `val1` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the value from your `input` at the moment the button is pressed:

```
document.querySelector('.js_update').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var val1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#value1').value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#value2').value);
    chart.update(Math.floor(val2));
});
```

In the above code only `val2` is used, but you'll understand the principle:

- The user clicks the button
- Two event handlers are called: `output` and the anonymous function above, linked by `addEventListener`
- The latter reads the text in the first `input`, and converts it to a number.
- The same is done for the second `input`
- Then the chart is updated

You have similar code for `output`, but please be aware that the order of execution is not defined. It might be that `output` executes before or after the above steps.

It would make more sense to use only one event handler for both tasks: doing the addition and updating the chart. So either put all code in `output` (chart business), or drop `output` and put the addition stuff in the function you have passed to `addEventListener`.